# Looking for a OSX alternative for baretail

Tags: osx, logs, log-analysis

On Windows, to view log files, I use [BareTailPro](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php). It's feature rich and I like the fact it provides:

- real-time update
- filtering
- coloring
- multiple files open in tabs
- indications of which tabs have been updated

I am looking for an OSX alternative that has these features.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative i just found is lnav from lnav.org. Source is available [on Github](https://github.com/tstack/lnav).

lnav is a highly configurable log viewer packed with features. I has coloring, filtering, advanced querying, real-time updating and much more. It runs in a command window, unlike lograpp which makes it easy, fast and very comfortable to use. For me, at least, i work more on the command line than in a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me answer my own question. I just found https://lograpp.wordpress.com/ and it looks like an almost exact copy of Baretail. Last update was from 2013, but it's still good enough for what i am looking for. The only thing missing is the grep function. I contacted the author to see if he is willing to get this into the program.

Answer (score 0):

OS X is Unix. Logs should be plain text, you can use `tail -f /path/to/log` to "watch" it, and you can `grep` that output as well.  I think the OS X version of `grep` has support for the `--color` option, if not you can install the GNU version via `homebrew`.  The terminal.app in OS X  supports tabs, and I believe it also indicates something on the tab for new output if that tab doesn't have focus.

Answer (score -1):

Try out [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). I have not really used this kind of software very much so I'm not sure how similar it is to BareTail.

Comment: No, they are two completely different type of software. Wireshark is a packet analyser where baretail is a log viewer.